# Can't multiply integer and double in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Java program where it calculates the total price of 3 differently valued items. Currently I'm trying to figure out why it won't let me multiply together a preset price and the amount inputted. Sorry for sloppy coding, I don't know Java basically at all. Here is code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SkillBuilder2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner values = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cupquantity;
        int lidquantity;
        int strawquantity;
        int cupprice;
        int lidprice;
        int strawprice;
        double cup = 0.05;
        double lids = 0.02;
        double straw = 0.03;
        System.out.println("How many cups do you want to purchase? ");
        cupquantity = (int) values.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many lids do you want to purchase? ");
        lidquantity = (int) values.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many straws do you want to purchase? ");
        strawquantity = (int) values.nextInt();
        cupprice = cup * cupquantity; // Here is where i am getting the error.
    }
}
```

Comment: It will let you multiply a double by an integer - but the result of that is a double, not an integer.

Comment: You can, but the result will be a `double`. You then need to convert it to an `int` as that's the type of `cupprice`. Take a look into casting.

Comment: (As an aside, if you only declare a variable at the point where it's first used, the code normally ends up being briefer and easier to read.)

Comment: Jon Skeet, You said why i'm getting the error but not the solution..

Comment: The solution is to assign the result to a variable that isn't an integer, or to explicitly cast the result back to an integer before making the assignment.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `cupprice` as an `int`. You will lose the cents. [It doesn't make much sense to have it as a floating-point value either in non-trivial code: it should be `BigDecimal`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cup is a double type, so if you multiply a double with int you will always have a double value.
Just change cupprice to double and everything will works fine

change line 10 to `double cupprice;`